# How to implement something like inpage expansion

Tags: javascript, html, css

currently I'm facing with a web-page design problem.

I'm trying to implement a function like Google Image Search. When I click on one image at Google Image Search, there will be a subpage show below the image I clicked.

I don't know how to describe or call this subpage. Is there anyone could tell me how to implement this or what kind of technology it is.

Here's the picture. (What Google did)
http://www.wy19900814fun.com/thumbnails/test.png

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  .container {
   text-align: center;
  }
  
  .container img {
   display:inline-block;
  }
  .subpage {
   display:none;
  }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/20964301401_5d9fdf5c0d_o_large_958fe482-f2e7-4120-b4fe-016fcf612bf5_large.jpeg?v=1440873580">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/20770321799_5c81882577_o_large_c4c19c91-0532-422f-99d0-297b2731c4e3_large.jpeg?v=1440873580">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/17108089939_8d4cefd10a_o_large_3dc1d49b-cb59-432a-a8d7-b118cfd61314_large.jpeg?v=1440873578">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/17950190230_114070818c_o_large_60ce5c71-7575-49ab-be75-ed2cfed6768d_large.jpeg?v=1440873577">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15175737319_c0db73446f_o_zps867eecb9_large_858814b0-6a80-4a34-b55d-97acc179cc91_large.jpeg?v=1440873576">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15085342999_b8878e538e_o_zps54a2d381_large_f731cd55-f8d0-4e9a-8ba5-c254b4b8241d_large.jpeg?v=1440873575">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15085523427_bacc983407_o_zps2c262937_large.jpeg?v=1440873574">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15268975561_ed3f9f5c0b_o_zpsd4857119_large.jpeg?v=1440873573">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/15339485796_bed118ac3c_o_zpsf0927ac3_large.jpeg?v=1440873572">
  <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0251/0700/products/IMG_9092_zpsc38bd27c_large.jpeg?v=1440873571">
 </div>
 
 <div class="subpage">
  <p>This is </br>just</br> a test.</br> Please show</br> subpage</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my code. Is there anyone could change my code to show a subpage that containing the information of second div. And show it below the image you click.

Comment: Start googling for "AJAX" and you'll get there.

Comment: This is achieved with very elementary AJAX and DOM manipulation. You're looking at ~10 lines of jQuery.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As said above, it's definitely AJAX. The answer to this question could be **really** extensive. I'll try to give you a simple answer, but the question is in the limit of StackOverflow-friendly and too-broad.

Comment: Thanks Marty, could you give me some material links besides w3cschool? That would be very helpful. Also some a little bit code would be perfect.

Comment: It's hard to give you any examples with no knowledge of your current skill level. There are several components you need to understand - attaching events to elements in the DOM, performing an AJAX request and translating the response into a series of elements that you add to the page.

Comment: Joaquín O, just some code to show the subpage but no detail information in the page would be fine. The problem I'm currently to deal with is that I try to write some javascript and show a subpage, but this page cannot take a whole line...

Comment: Marty, OK I'll try to understand some basic AJAX technology then give you more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you're gonna need:

1. Knowledge of/learning HTML basis
2. Knowledge of/learning javascript basis
3. Knowledge of/learning AJAX basis
4. Knowledge of/learning any server-side language
5. Probably (and desired) MySQL or some DB language.

---

### Basic steps for implementing it

1. Generate your HTML with every image
2. Use javascript to bind click event to every image
3. Use AJAX to make a request to your server
4. Use your server-side language (and desired DB) to get the image data (title, info, external-link, or whatever)
5. Parse the response using JS and manipulate the DOM to add and show the new data.

---

### Recommended resources

For learning: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/)
For reference: [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript)

---

Hope this help you out for a kickoff. Have good coding.

Comment: Thank you so much, but currently I think I've finished step 1234, I will try to rearrange all the words and I'll show my current code. I just don't know how to arrange the webpage layout to display a subpage to show new data.

Comment: OK, I don't know why the downvote but please edit the question and then I'll try to edit the answer or delete it in any other case..

Comment: The downvote is not me... I cannot vote currently. sorry about that.

Comment: I've finished rearranging words, plz see it now.